# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list" // for a function with 2 list parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

What I'm trying to do is make a function that takes 2 lists of the same size and returns a new list with the products. Example `x = [1,2,3]` and `y = [4,5,6]` will return a list `[4,10,18]`

This is what I have so far:

```
def mult_list(x=[],y=[]):
    z = []
    for i in (x,y):
        if len(x) == len(y):
            z.append(x[i]*y[i])
        else:
            print("length of list not equal")
    return x,y
```

But I'm getting the error when I try something like: `mult_list([8,1,4,8],[2,5,5,8])` to test the code.

And when I test lists of unequal size like `mult_list([8,1,8],[2,5,5,8])`

I get

```
>>> mult_list([8,1,8],[2,5,5,8])
length of list not equal
length of list not equal
([8, 1, 8], [2, 5, 5, 8])
```

in my output, which I'm guessing is wrong since it repeats the print statement twice for some reason ...

Comment: What do you think `for i in (x,y):` is doing? Why do you check the length inside the loop? Why do you return the inputs? Also note https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/3001761

Comment: 1) Thought it looked at the values in `x` and `y` which I assumed would be defined as lists according the the parameter. 2) I thought the for loop was needed for that if/else statement, so if  the length wasn't equal the "else" would print out that t's not equal. 3) I thought you return parameters (if any) at the end of a function.

Comment: 1. Yes, so `i` is the list. Then what did you think e.g. `x[x]` would do? 2. That doesn't make sense. 3. You *can*, but you don't *have to* (indeed it's generally unidiomatic to do so and Python) and, perhaps most importantly **that's not what you're saying you want the function to return**. I'd recommend you investigate this with e.g. http://pythontutor.com/, there's too much trivially wrong to sensibly address here.

Comment: 1) Confused about about where you're getting `x[x]` from. 2) So is there no if/else statement at all?? I thought the point of the for loop was to check if the lengths of `x` and `y` are equal, do the multiplication if they are equal, else print that we won't multiply it because the size of lists  `x` and `y` are not equal. 3) So how would you return a function that contains if/else statements, if not by addressing the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First, `for i in (x, y)` does not really make much sense. This will just assign `i` first to `x` and then to `y`. Assuming `i` is the index, you want `for i in range(len(x))`. This assumes that the length are equal, which you should check first, not in each iteration of the loop (that's why the `print` was repeated). Finally, you have to return `z`, not `x, y`. Also, the default parameters `x=[], y=[]` do not make much sense IMHO.

```
def mult_list(x, y):
    z = []
    if len(x) == len(y):
        for i in range(len(x)):
            z.append(x[i]*y[i])
        return z
    else:
        print("length of list not equal")
```

This can be improved, though, using `zip(x, y)` to get pairs of corresponding values from `x` and `y` -- that's probably what you had in mind with `for i in (x, y)`.

```
def mult_list(x, y):
    z = []
    if len(x) == len(y):
        for xi, yi in zip(x, y):
            z.append(xi * yi)
        return z
    else:
        print("length of list not equal")
```

Finally, we can replace that multi-line `for` loop with a simple list comprehension:

```
def mult_list(x, y):
    if len(x) == len(y):
        return [xi * yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y)]
    else:
        print("length of list not equal")
```

Comment: My class hasn't learned zip yet, but the first block of code you posted works and makes sense! Thank you!